# Quadratic JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple code for solving quadratic equations with HTML and JavaScript. I cannot find my error in this code.

I'm not getting any output (alert) when I click the Calculate button.

Script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function quadraticformula()
{
    var a = document.getElementById(variablea).value;
    var b = document.getElementById(variableb).value;
    var c = document.getElementById(variablec).value;


    var p = (-b);
    var q = (b*b);
    var r = (4*a*c);
    var s = (q-r);
    var t = (math.sqrt(s));
    var u = (2*a);

    var v = ((p + t) / u);
    var w = ((p - t) / u);

    document.write("x=" + v + ", x=" + w);
    alert("x=" + v + ", x=" + w);
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="va" id="variablea" size="3"> x<sup>2</sup>+</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="vb" id="variableb" size="3"> x+</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="vc" id="variablec" size="3"> = 0 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowspan="2">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate" onclick="quadraticformula()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</form>
```

Comment: `Math.sqrt(s)`. You should get an error in your browser console. Also [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), especially not in an event handler.

Comment: Your page becomes blank as soon as you run the function. try something other then `document.write`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Javascript may be not interpreted correctly.. Try with this (Which is HTML 5 complient.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also, when using `document.getElementById(variablea)`. You want to direct the element which is referenced by a string. You must then put quotes :

```
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("variablea").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("variableb").value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("variablec").value);
```

There is also a typo in your function. Use `Math.sqrt(s)` with a capital M.

Edit: And as @Bergi and @Teemu as pointed out, don't use `document.write` in an event.

Comment: How about the typo and `document.write()` in an eventhandler?

Comment: edited my post. but didn't find the typo you are talking about.

Comment: @NMC Teemu is talking about the lowercase `m` in `math.sqrt`. it should be capital as in `Math.sqrt`

Comment: thanks, does partly work. I do get the alert dialogue but the output I get is x=NAN, x=NAN. Maybe I did not convert the strings into an Int, I tried doing it but i still get the same output. plz help

Comment: var a = document.getElementById("variablea").value;
  parseInt(document.getElementById("variablea").value);
  var b = document.getElementById("variableb").value;
  parseInt(document.getElementById("variableb").value);
  var c = document.getElementById("variablec").value;
  parseInt(document.getElementById("variablec").value);

Comment: updated my answer with the correct use of parsint.. you don't need to put them 2 times oin your code. Also, if my answer helped you, could you select it as the right answer?